# In Unity, a blue screen is showing in 2d core how do i quit it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get this blue screen whenever I open or create a new project                                                      [my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9yS5.png)
I don't know if it is just 2d or anything else. Can anybody tell me the solution? and if anyone has encountered something how did you face it. I can make gameobject and it is displayed on the middle of the blue screen.

Comment: Click the layout button in the top right corner and choose 'Default' and you should be able to get all the default windows back.

Answer (score 1):

its a normal background in unity 2D. don't worry my friend :)
you can change color "Main Camera" - "Inspector" - "Camera" - "Clear Flags" - "Solid Color"